# Show many statistical graphs with chart

Tags: javascript, charts

Good afternoon, I am working on a website and the need arose to create some visual statistics and I started using chart. The problem is that I need to show many statistics of the same type once data is loaded, so I am using a simple foreach to traverse the array, but only show once and with the latest data loaded.

```
<?php foreach ($datos as $d){
<div id="canvas-holder" style="width:100%">
          <canvas id="chart-area"></canvas>
        </div>
        <script>
          var config = {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
              datasets: [{
                data:[
                  <?php foreach ($estadistica1 as $s){
                    echo $s['p'];?>,<?php echo $s['s'];?>,<?php echo $s['f'];}?>],

                backgroundColor: [
                  "rgba(15,255,0)",
                  "rgba(255,243,0)",
                  "rgba(255,0,0)",
                ],
                label: 'Dataset 1'
              }],
              labels: ['dato1', 'dato2', 'dato3'],
            },
            options: {
            }
          };

          window.onload = function() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('chart-area').getContext('2d');
            window.myPie = new Chart(ctx, config);
          };

          var colorNames = Object.keys(window.chartColors);
          document.getElementById('addDataset').addEventListener('click', function() {
            var newDataset = {
              backgroundColor: [],
              data: [],
              label: 'New dataset ' + config.data.datasets.length,
            };

            config.data.datasets.push(newDataset);
            window.myPie.update();
          });

        </script>
}?>
```

My first impression is the "id" it contains when calling javascript, but I want to know what can be a possible solution.

Comment: 1) It's not very clear whar the problem is. Describe the desired and the current behavior of the code.  
2) Look at the parsed source code from the browser. I don't know what you php objects look like but I guess you don't get valid javascript.  
3) You use the ids ```canvas-holder``` and ```chart-area``` multiple times. This will cause trouble, ids have to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the id is one problem with this code. Each time the loop runs

`var ctx = document.getElementById('chart-area').getContext('2d');`

`ctx` refers to the same element in the DOM, so it replaces whatever was there previously. One solution would be to dynamically generate the id based on the index of the loop iteration, ie `chart-area-0`, `chart-area-1`, etc.

Another problem is the way PHP and Javascript are mixed together. This makes it unnecessarily difficult to read and understand what it happening in your code. For example, I don't see `$d` being used. And it looks like you are trying to loop through both the values of `$datos` and then `$estadistica1`. Is that intended?

If you have to get your values from PHP, I suggest doing so once and allow Javascript to handle looping through the values to create the charts.

You can get your PHP values into Javascript objects like this:

```
<script>
  var datos = <?php echo json_encode($datos); ?>;
  var estadistica1 = <?php echo json_encode($estadistica1); ?>;
</script>
```

Then in your code, you can use those values in pure Javascript. Something like this:

```
<div id="canvas-holder" style="width: 100%"></div>

<script>
  var datos = <?php echo json_encode($datos); ?>;
  var estadistica1 = <?php echo json_encode($estadistica1); ?>;
  var config = [];

  // create an array of config objects, one for each chart
  // your original code doesn't use d, so it's unclear what it does
  datos.forEach(function(d) {
    var data = [];
    estadistica1.forEach(function(s) {
      data.push([s.p, s.s, s.f]);
    });

    var thisConfig = {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
        datasets: [{
          data: data,
          backgroundColor: [
            "rgba(15,255,0)",
            "rgba(255,243,0)",
            "rgba(255,0,0)",
          ],
          label: 'Dataset 1'
        }],
        labels: ['dato1', 'dato2', 'dato3'],
      },
      options: {
      }
    };
    config.push(thisConfig);
  });

  window.onload = function() {
    var canvasContainer = document.getElementById("canvas-holder");
    config.forEach(function(thisConfig, index) {
      var thisCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      var thisId = "chart-area-" + index;
      thisCanvas.setAttribute("id", thisId);
      canvasContainer.appendChild(thisCanvas);
      var thisCtx = document.getElementById(thisId).getContext('2d');
      new Chart(thisCtx, thisConfig);
  });
</script>
```

I have omitted the `addEventListener` code as it looks like that was incomplete and it was not clear what the purpose of it is.

I haven't tested this code since I don't have access to your PHP values.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, the problem is in the id. But when trying to modify it or pass it to a class all the graphics disappear. I suppose it must be because the id is included in the script library.

Comment: This id is not part of the script library - you decide what to call the id when you create the `canvas` tag:
`<canvas id="chart-area"></canvas>`
You can call it whatever you want. You just have to use the same `id` here: `var ctx = document.getElementById('chart-area').getContext('2d');` In your code, you are overwriting the contents of the canvas with the id of `chart-area` each time the loop runs. You need a unique id for each chart. You can create multiple canvas tags with unique ids, but you will need a way to change the `getElementById` call to match the ids in your canvas tags.